# obs-websocket-js play audio url

Tags: node.js, obs, obs-studio

I need to switch the scene and play an audio file through a third party url

Previously it could have been done something like this

```
const OBSWebSocket = require('obs-websocket-js');
const obs = new OBSWebSocket();

obs.connect(obsSettings)
   .then(() => {
         obs.send('SetCurrentScene', { 'scene-name': 'YourSceneName' });
         obs.send('PlayAudio', { source: 'YourAudioSourceName', file: url });
             console.log('Audio playback started');
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.error(`OBS connection error: ${err}`);
  });
```

but now the `obs.send` command does not work, instead of it `obs.call`, and let’s say to change the scene I need to use this code

```
obs.call('SetCurrentProgramScene', { sceneName: 'YourSceneName' });
```

But how can I play audio in obs? I can't find how this is currently implemented

In general, the essence of my question is to translate the text in a voice message and display it in obs

This is how I do things

```
const voiceUrl = googleTTS.getAudioUrl(response, {
       lang: 'en',
       slow: false,
       host: 'https://translate.google.com',
  });
console.log(`Voice message: ${voiceUrl}`);
playVoice('Voice', voiceUrl);
```

I get a link to this voice message, then call the `playVoice` function to play it in obs

```
const OBSWebSocket = require('obs-websocket-js').default;
const obs = new OBSWebSocket();

function playVoice(sourceName, voiceUrl) {
    obs.call('SetCurrentProgramScene', { sceneName: 'Main' });
    obs.call('PlayAudio', { source: sourceName, file: voiceUrl });
}
```

`SetCurrentProgramScene` with scene change works as it should. But how can I play this audio through url? `PlayAudio` request not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exact answer to your question, I think the websocket api seems not to support this sort of activity anymore (see https://github.com/obsproject/obs-websocket/blob/master/docs/generated/protocol.md#requests ) Have you thought different approach to this problem:

You could do just web app using node and express + socket.io... and serve empty (and transparent) webpage that plays the audio using javascript and  tag and add the page as browser source.

Comment: I was thinking about this, about creating a separate web page and displaying it in OBS, and in any case I will come to this solution if it doesn’t work out that way. Just wondering if it is possible to directly transfer audio to OBS or not

Answer (score 0):

With OBS WebSocket, you can play any audio stream as you would do it manually.

But the command ***PlayAudio*** you mentioned does not exist.

Instead you should use ***TriggerMediaInputAction*** like below

```
obs.call('TriggerMediaInputAction', { inputName: your_source_name, mediaAction: "OBS_WEBSOCKET_MEDIA_INPUT_ACTION_RESTART"});
```

This only works if you have already setup correctly *your_source_name* in the scene.

You can do it manually or programmaticaly (by using ***CreateInput***)

You should refer to ***CreateInput*** documentation to do so.
As this is beyond your original question, i'm not going to elaborate on this subject.
You can still ask if you need helps.